# Android: issues with character encoding in URI

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, uri, google-geocoder

In my Android code I construct a URL which includes an options string.

In Android I encode the options string using [`Uri.encode(options)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String)) and then on the server side (running `node.js`) I use [`decodeURIComponent(options)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp).

Generally speaking this is working just fine.  For example, "München" goes in at the Android end, and "München" comes out at the server end.

But just occasionally, I'm getting "M�nchen" at the server after decoding.

Before running `decodeURIComponent()` on the options, this amounts to `M%EF%BF%BDnchen` rather than the correct `M%C3%BCnchen`.

It seems strange that this would happen... I'd expect a consistent encoding/decoding for all instances where "München" is at the input.

Is this known behaviour?  Perhaps I can use a different encoding/decoding scheme?

I can't yet detect a pattern, since the instances are quite rare, but I think that Android 5 has been involved in each case I've seen so far.

What occurs to me is that the issue may go back one step further... the place name "München" is from a [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) lookup along the following lines:

```
String lookupString = "Munich Germany"; // in practice this would be entered by the user at runtime
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault()); // default locale is 'de' so 'München' should be returned
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(lookupString, 1);
Address address = addresses.get(0);
String placeName = address.getLocality(); // should be München
```

So maybe the issue is at this stage?  But again, I'm using the same `Geocoder` class in all cases, so really I shouldn't get "München" in one case and "M�nchen" in another??

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Java-file is in UTF-8 encoding.

I've tested your code by using "de" (not default for me), it retuns correctly worked String:

```
String lookupString = "Munich Germany";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, new Locale("de"));
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(lookupString, 1);
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String placeName = address.getLocality(); // should be München
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Check `Charset.defaultCharset()` method.

Comment: Hmm, OK.  That did actually cross my mind but I dismissed it because my understanding is that the encoding of the place name that is looked up would not be affected by the encoding of the Java code file itself... I am not hard coding "München" into the code but looking it up programmatically.

Comment: @drmrbrewer , Where do you receive this string? Check each char number to compare .

Comment: As explained in the post, the string is from the `Geocoder` lookup -- see `String placeName` in the code snippet

Comment: @drmrbrewer , tested on my device. It seems to be workable code.

Comment: So, any suggestion as to why, for *some* users on *some* devices, it's coming out the end as "M�nchen", while for most users it's coming out correctly as "München"?

Comment: @drmrbrewer , first of all . have you tried to use force `new Locale("de")`?

Comment: @drmrbrewer , check , for example this (encoding in Eclipse): Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding